# Why is it showing stack overflow exception when i call mergesort on the first half of the linked list

Tags: java, exception, linked-list, mergesort

```java
public class Solution {

    public static LinkedListNode<Integer> mergeSort(LinkedListNode<Integer> head) {
        //Your code goes 
         LinkedListNode slow=head, fast=head, temp=head;
         while(fast!=null && fast.next!=null){
             temp=slow;
             fast=fast.next.next;
             slow=slow.next;
         }
          temp.next=null;
          LinkedListNode left_side=mergeSort(head);
          LinkedListNode right_side=mergeSort(slow);

          return merge(left_side, right_side);
    }

    public static LinkedListNode merge(LinkedListNode<Integer> head1, LinkedListNode<Integer> head2){
       LinkedListNode temp_node=new LinkedListNode(0);
       LinkedListNode current_node= temp_node;

       while(head1!=null && head2!=null){
           if(head1.data<=head2.data){
               current_node.next=head1;
               head1=head1.next;
           }else{
               current_node.next=head2;
               head2=head2.next;
           }
           current_node=current_node.next;
       }
       if(head1!=null){
          current_node.next=head1;
          head1=head1.next;
       }
       if(head2!=null){
           current_node=head2;
           head2=head2.next;
       }
       
       return temp_node.next;


   }
}
```

I was expecting a sorted list but I'm getting a `StackOverflowError`.

How should I correct it? The error is shown specifically for the line where I call `mergSort` on the left side of the linked list. What should I do?

Comment: You might consider a [bottom up merge sort for linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists), which skips all the scanning of lists to split them. It uses a small array (24 to 32) of references to list, where arrray[i] is either empty or references a list with 2^i nodes. Node are merged into the array one at a time, then the array of lists are merged to create a single sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursion in mergeSort() method and there is no exit condition for the mergeSort function. you should have an exit condition before calling recursion. Otherwise it will keep on calling the same method until the stack becomes full. thus stack overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

thumbs already answered the question. If interested, here are bottom up and top  down merge sort single linked list examples. Bottom up is faster, how much faster depends on number of nodes and if nodes are scattered (cache misses). It's faster still to copy the list to an array, sort the array, then create a new sorted list from the array. The merge function is the same for both examples: the if(true){head...} ... while(true){dest ...} is done to avoid using a dummy node (which avoids allocating and freeing a dummy node on every call to merge).

bottom up

```
    // bottom up merge sort for single link list
    static Node sortbu(Node head) {
        final int NUMLIST = 32;
        Node[] alist = new Node[NUMLIST];
        Node node;
        Node next;
        int i;
        // if < 2 nodes, return
        if(head == null || head.next == null)
            return null;
        node = head;
        // merge node into array
        while(node != null){
            next = node.next;
            node.next = null;
            for(i = 0; (i < NUMLIST) && (alist[i] != null); i++){
                node = merge(alist[i], node);
                alist[i] = null;
            }
            if(i == NUMLIST)   // don't go past end of array
                i--;
            alist[i] = node;
            node = next;
        }
        // node == null
        // merge array into single list
        for(i = 0; i < NUMLIST; i++)
            node = merge(alist[i], node);
        return node;
    }

    // merge two already sorted lists
    static Node merge(Node list0, Node list1) {
        if(list0 == null)
            return list1;
        if(list1 == null)
            return list0;
        Node head;
        Node dest;
        if(true){
            if(list0.data <= list1.data){
                head = list0;
                dest = list0;
                list0 = list0.next;
                if(list0 == null){
                    dest.next = list1;
                    return head;
                }
            } else {
                head = list1;
                dest = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
                if(list1 == null){
                    dest.next = list0;
                    return head;
                }
            }
        }
        while(true){
            if(list0.data <= list1.data){
                dest.next = list0;
                dest = list0;
                list0 = list0.next;
                if(list0 == null){
                    dest.next = list1;
                    return head;
                }
            } else {
                dest.next = list1;
                dest = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
                if(list1 == null){
                    dest.next = list0;
                    return head;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

top down

```
    // top down merge sort for single link list entry function
    static Node sorttd(Node head) {
        int n = size(head);
        if(n < 2)
            return head;
        head = sorttdr(head, n);
        return head;
    }

    // top down merge sort for single link list recursive function
    static Node sorttdr(Node head, int n) {
        if(n < 2)
            return head;
        int n2 = (n/2);
        Node node = advance(head, n2-1);
        Node next = node.next;
        node.next = null;
        head = sorttdr(head, n2);
        next = sorttdr(next, n-n2);
        head = merge(head, next);
        return head;
    }

    // return size of list
    static int size(Node head) {
    int i = 0;
        while(head != null){
            head = head.next;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    // advance to node n
    static Node advance(Node head, int n) {
        while(0 < n--)
            head = head.next;
        return head;
    }

    // merge two already sorted lists
    static Node merge(Node list0, Node list1) {
        if(list0 == null)
            return list1;
        if(list1 == null)
            return list0;
        Node head;
        Node dest;
        if(true){
            if(list0.data <= list1.data){
                head = list0;
                dest = list0;
                list0 = list0.next;
                if(list0 == null){
                    dest.next = list1;
                    return head;
                }
            } else {
                head = list1;
                dest = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
                if(list1 == null){
                    dest.next = list0;
                    return head;
                }
            }
        }
        while(true){
            if(list0.data <= list1.data){
                dest.next = list0;
                dest = list0;
                list0 = list0.next;
                if(list0 == null){
                    dest.next = list1;
                    return head;
                }
            } else {
                dest.next = list1;
                dest = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
                if(list1 == null){
                    dest.next = list0;
                    return head;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```